# Polygon complete not able to show lat long value for v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am moving from V2 gmap to V3. I need to draw polylines,polygon and point individually to mark geo fence area. In my v2 after drawing is complete I get a pop-up window and add the necessary details and able to save into db. Here I managed to use the drawing tool now I have this function. The problem the lat and long value are not shown and therefore I am not able to show up my infowindow any help on this. I need for polyline and also the markers.

Sample codes.

```
    var points = e.getPath();
    alert("POL COMPLETE"+points.length);
    var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

     for (var i =0; i < points.length; i++) {
                var xy = points.getAt(i);
                alert("Coordinate: " + i + "<br />" + xy.lat() +"," + xy.lng());
                latlngbounds.extend(points(i)); 
     }

    alert("CS : "+latlngbounds.getCenter());
var contentString="TESTTT";
         var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});
          infowindow.setPosition(latlngbounds.getCenter());
        infowindow.open(map);

              var newShape = e.overlay;
              selectedShape = newShape;

            google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow,'closeclick',function(){
           alert("TEST");
           selectedShape.setMap(null); //removes the marker
   // then, remove the infowindows name from the array
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A polygon doesn't have a `latLng`-property. It does have a path, use `e.getPath()` to access this path.

For a polyline also use `e.getPath()` and for a marker use `e.getPosition()`

Comment: thank you but once complete I want to pop-up the info window wat is the best mechanism for that please?

Comment: call the open-method of the infoWindow. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows

Comment: I have gone to this site before because back in V2 I get the lat long and assign the window to it. In this case also it need the latlong for it to open at that location right? That is my problem how to get the lat long for polygon and infowindow.open(map,marker); in this line is the marker how to establish that?

Comment: create a LatLngBounds-object from the vertices of the polygon. The setCenter-method of this LatLngBounds returns a LatLng which may be assigned to the position-property of the infowindow.(use `infoWindow.setPosition()` to set the position, a LatLng will not be accepted as 2nd argument of `infoWindow.open()`)

Comment: I have update my question with the latest codes and stuck here latlngbounds.extend(points(i)); this is not working. Even tried latlngbounds.extend(points[i]);. Please advice.

Comment: solve it supposed to be latlngbounds.extend(points.getAt(i));

Comment: great I am able to pop-up the infoWindow now if I press the X button I want to clear anything on drawn on the map how it that possible?

Comment: I also manage to come out with X close listener but is not clearing my shape